# Jquery validator plugin ajax submition not triggering

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I have a problem with my the Jquery validator (http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/) plugins submitHandler function. The form is validated correctly and the invalid handler message triggers correctly, but the submitHandler functions will not trigger correctly and the ajaxSubmit function does not trigger corectly. Any one see what I have done wrong? Any help would be most wellcome.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
var submitMessage     = $('#submit-message'),
    messageContainer  = submitMessage.find('span'),
    loading           = $('#loading');

function showSuccess(message) {
    messageContainer.text(message)
    messageContainer.attr('class', 'success');
  }
function showFailure(message) {
    messageContainer.text(message)
    messageContainer.attr('class', 'failure');
}
$("#contact-form-info").validate({
  rules: {
    contact_Name: {
      minlength: 2,
      maxlength: 50,
      required: true
    },
    contact_Foretag: {
      minlength: 1,
      maxlength: 50
    },
    contact_Email: {
      required: true,
      email: true
    },
    contact_Subject: {
      required: true,
      minlength: 5,
      maxlength: 50
    },
    contact_Message: {
      required: true,
      minlength: 10,
      maxlength: 5000
    }
  },
  submitHandler: function(form) {
        var options = {
            beforeSubmit: function() {
                loading.show();
            },
            success: function() {
                showSuccess('Thank you! Your email has been submitted.');
                form.reset();
                loading.hide();
            },
            error: function() {
                showFailure("We're sorry, your email could not be sent. Please try again later.");
                loading.hide();
            }
        };
        $(form).ajaxSubmit(options);
     return false;

    },
    invalidHandler: function() {
        showFailure('There were some problems with your submission.');
    }
 });
});
</script>
```

Here is my code in jsFiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/JwNmK/

Comment: What JavaScript errors do you get in the console?   And where is the form's HTML?

Comment: What exactly does _"does not trigger correctly"_ mean?

Comment: It means that when I submit a valid form it is submited as a "normal" form, I am redirected to the process.php page. @Sparky There are no errors in the console btw, that I can see.

Comment: If it's submitted as a normal form with a redirect, that's because you have not blocked normal submit from happening.  See my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**OP's comment**:

> "when I submit a valid form it is submited as a 'normal' form, I am
>   redirected to the process.php page"

You definitely need a `return false` at the end of your `submitHandler` callback function when using `ajax`.

```
submitHandler: function (form) {
    // your ajax
    return false;
},
```

Comment: This solution did not work, I am updating my code so you can see where I added return false.

Comment: @StenW, it should be the very last line in the `submitHandler`.  Please show your form's HTML code and construct a jsFiddle demo.

Comment: @StenW, [your jsFiddle is useless](http://jsfiddle.net/JwNmK/)... no HTML in there... nothing rendered... no demo of anything... just the same JavaScript as in your OP.

Comment: O, sorry for that one. I will fix it!

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/JwNmK/4/ All the HTMl is now where it should be I hope. @Sparky Thank you again man!